# WCF serialization is slow at the first call

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm using .Net 3.5 SP1, working with the default WCF serializer - DataContractSerializer.
I have this simple interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void RecieveInteger(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    void RecieveBigDataType(BigDataType value);
}
```

My client does the following:

1. Invokes 'RecieveInteger' just to warm-up the service.
2. Invokes 'RecieveBigDataType' 10 times and measure performance.

Measuring the 10 calls to  'RecieveBigDataType', I found the first call is much slower than the others. It seems like the first time WCF needs to serialize the type 'BigDataType' is happening very slow.
Any ideas to make the first call faster?

Comment: How your test from client ? . .means Created ServiceClient object once and call it 10 times or each time you created new serviceclient and call method.

Comment: Creating only one ServiceClient object, and then doing actions 1-2 written above.

Comment: 1. When you create object first time 
2. Then you make call to web service first time it will create communication channgel at that time. So when next time call hapeend it continuously use that channel so sub sequent call is faster. Try to create ServiceClient each time and measure performance diffrent.

Comment: dotnetstep, this is why i called the 'RecieveInteger' service first.
The calls that involve the 'BigDataType' are the issue here.

Comment: Sorry Sean, no idea but if you find the answer, please post back on here with it.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, for the XmlSerializer,

**Initializing XmlSerializer by Calling FromTypes on Startup**

*The first time XmlSerializer encounters a type, it generates code to perform serialization and then it caches that code for later use. However, if you call the FromTypes static method on the XmlSerializer, it forces XmlSerializer to immediately generate and cache the required code for the types you plan to serialize. This reduces the time taken to serialize a specific type for the first time. The following example shows this approach.*

```
static void OnApplicationStart()
{
  Type[] myTypes = new Type[] { Type.GetType("customer"), Type.GetType("order") };
  XmlSerializer.FromTypes( myTypes );
}
```

I know you are using WCF which uses DataContractSerializer, but there maybe some way to do the same thing.

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650685.aspx

Comment: i've tried it (also changed my serializer to xmlSerializer for the test), unfortunately there's no improvement.

Comment: Maybe your spin-up time is on a per-service-operation basis then.

Comment: It is a serialization issue for sure. If i'll call another service operation afterwards (with the same parameter) it'll be fast. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same issue with `DataContractJsonSerializer`. In my case first call of `DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(..)` took 1.3 sec more then other calls for the same object.
To be honestly the serialized object had some interfaces, so `KnownTypes` had to be defined.

The only work around I had found was to run a `Task` on application start and serialize dummy objects of known types.
Interesting is that on the thread pool serialization of dummy objects took 0.5 sec less time than on GUI.

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var knownTypes = new[] { typeof(ServiceImpl_1), typeof(ServiceImpl_2), typeof(ServiceImpl_3)};
    var ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
                (
                    typeof(IService),
                    new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { KnownTypes = knownTypes }
                );

    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        foreach(var tp in knownTypes)
        {
            object inst = null;
            try
            {
                foreach(var ctorInf in tp.GetConstructors())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var prInfos = ctorInf.GetParameters();
                        if(prInfos.Length == 0)
                        {
                            inst = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var parList = new object[prInfos.Length];
                            for(int i = 0; i < prInfos.Length; i++)
                            {
                                parList[i] = prInfos[i].ParameterType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(prInfos[i].ParameterType) : null;
                            }
                            inst = Activator.CreateInstance(tp, parList);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    ser.WriteObject(ms, inst);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exc) {}
        }
    }
}
```